# Porcentagem em C

Tags: c, matemática, porcentagem

Dado o seguinte enunciado:

> Escreva um algoritmo para mostrar na tela se cada número N, digitado
>   pelo usuário é par ou ímpar. O algoritmo também deverá mostrar na tela
>   a soma de todos os números pares, a soma de todos os números ímpares,
>   a porcentagem de números pares e a porcentagem de números ímpares
>   digitados. O algoritmo deverá encerrar sua execução caso o usuário
>   digite um número menor que zero.

Escrevi o seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

     int main()
     {

     int N;
     int somapar = 0;
     int somaimpar = 0;
     float porcentagemi = 1;
     float porcentagemp = 1;

     do{
      printf("\n Digite um número qualquer: ");
      scanf("%d", &N);

     if (N % 2 == 0){
      printf("\n Número escolhido é par!");
      somapar += N;
     }

     else {
      printf("\n Número escolhido é ímpar");
      somaimpar += N;
     }

     printf("\n Soma total de ímpares é %d e soma total de pares é %d\n", somaimpar, somapar);

     porcentagemp = (somapar/(somapar + somaimpar))*100;
     porcentagemi = (somaimpar/(somapar + somaimpar))*100;

     printf("\n Porcentagem de pares é: %f", porcentagemp);
     printf("\n Porcentagem de ímpares é: %f\n", porcentagemi);

     }while (N >= 0);

     return 0;
     }
```

Mas o programa não está retornando a porcentagem corretamente. Quando digito um numero par e um numero ímpar em seguida, ao invés do programa me retornar 50% cada, ele ZERA os dois.

Comment: Ele deve estar zerando as variáveis por causa do escopo coloca as variáveis que não deseja que se percam fora da função main ou seja no escopo global

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisa tirar a porcentagem de dentro do laço, ela só pode ser calculada depois de ter todos os dados. Além disso é precisa garantir que a divisão seja feita como `float` para ter casas decimais. Na forma atual ela dá um inteiro e a conta fica imprecisa para o que deseja, então um membro precisa ser ponto flutuante.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int N;
    int somapar = 0;
    int somaimpar = 0;
    do {
        printf("\n Digite um número qualquer: ");
        scanf("%d", &N);
        if (N % 2 == 0) {
            printf("\n Número escolhido é par!");
            somapar += N;
        } else {
            printf("\n Número escolhido é ímpar");
            somaimpar += N;
        }
    } while (N >= 0);
    printf("\nTotal de ímpares é %d e total de pares é %d\n", somaimpar, somapar);
    float total = somapar + somaimpar;
    float porcentagemPar = somapar / total * 100.0f;
    float porcentagemImpar = somaimpar / total * 100.0f;
    printf("Porcentagem de pares é: %f\n", porcentagemPar);
    printf("Porcentagem de ímpares é: %f\n", porcentagemImpar);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vGYin6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vjqavejd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/EvenOdd.c).